# wi-fi working on and off, mostly off on a HP laptop

Tags: wifi, xubuntu

I have a HP laptop with Intel Centrino 2230 card. The system is Xubuntu 13. Wifi worked fine until it stopped a couple of days or maybe weeks ago. Now it's mostly off with some on episodes.

Specifics: I can connect to a network and obtain an IP address, but can't ping the gateway. The network has WPA2. Setting wlan0 down and up doesn't help.

Any idea on how to fix it?

EDIT after the response:

Windows WIFI on the same laptop works fine, so it's an issue with Linux configuration. I remember turning off N mode (don't remember how) because wi-fi was slow, that helped with speed.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot from a LiveUSB and see if the problem persists. That would eliminate software issues on your local HDD/SSD.

If so, I'd suggest checking the mechanicals; dismount and then reattach the WLAN card. After all, [Pournelle's Law](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/73327/More_Eternal_Verities) states "Cables do matter. When something doesn't work, always check the cables and their connectors first."  It certainly seems to apply to intermittants like this.